# Get images from a video in every N frames

Tags: image, video, media-player, video-capture, video-processing

I am looking for some tool or program to automatically grab snapshots (a few mins interval) from a video file without display it for me. Mkv support would be nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ffmpeg manual page http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html :

```
For extracting images from a video:


ffmpeg -i foo.avi -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg

This will extract one video frame per second from the video and will output them in files named ‘foo-001.jpeg’, ‘foo-002.jpeg’, etc. Images will be rescaled to fit the new WxH values.
```

There are other options for extracting images depending on frame position or time, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I found some command for vlc too. C:\VideoLAN\VLC>vlc "C:\videos\hello.mov" --video-filter=scene 
   --vout=dummy --start-time=1 --stop-time=5 --scene-ratio=1 
   --scene-prefix=img- --scene-path=C:\images\ vlc://quit